# Updated wordpress title in get_the_title not showing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use  in my wordpress templates successfully but if I edit the title name, still the first title is displayed.

**Example:**

01.01.2022 I set up a page with the title "Placeholder"

12.04.2022 I edit the pages' title to "Supercool cars and stuff"

echoed title is still (even months afterwards and without any caching issue and on completely different machines) "Placeholder"

How would I make Wordpress the correct most updated title?